# TrimRight not working as I expected

Tags: go

Below is the code of TrimRight, on latest Go version

I am observing a behavior, which maybe I am misunderstanding but as my understanding, the below code should throw output as

```
Hello
```

But the output is coming as

```
Hell
```

Why is that so ? Note, I have kept a space before the Gophers in cutset, so fundamentally it should remove the " Gophers" from the primary string, leaving behind just Hello

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    result := strings.TrimRight("Hello Gophers", " Gophers")

    fmt.Println(result, len(result))
}
```

Comment: You should not code code to your expectations but to the sepcification of the function as documented.-

Comment: I did see the documentation. In fact the piece of code I picked up from documentation. If you go and check TrimRight, you would see that. The sentence of doc confused me and for that I should be given some consideration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented, [`TrimRight`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimRight) removes all matching characters from the right. Because `o` is included in your list (`" Gophers"`), it is also trimmed. If you want to trim that exact substring use [`TrimSuffix`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSuffix) instead.

Comment: But if you remove the space before Gophers in the cutset, then the result is Hello. Even then character o is present in cutset

Comment: Yes, because then `o` is no longer in the set of right-most matching characters.

Comment: `TrimRight` trims all trailing characters in the cutset. If space is not in your cutset, then the `o` in `Hello` is no longer trailing, because it is succeeded by a non-cutset character (the space).

Comment: If your input is "Gophers, Hello Gophers", and you `TrimRight()` with a cutset of "Gophers", you wouldn't expect the first word "Gophers" to be trimmed, would you?